# Angular PWA: no matching service worker detected

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

This is my configuration:

```
Angular CLI: 8.2.1
Node: 10.15.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.1
... animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.802.1
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.802.1
@angular-devkit/core              8.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.2.1
@angular/cdk                      8.1.2
@angular/material                 8.1.2
@angular/pwa                      0.802.1
@ngtools/webpack                  8.2.1
@schematics/angular               8.2.1
@schematics/update                0.802.1
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.38.0
```

I ran `ng add @angular/pwa`. It created the following *ngsw-config.json*:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    }, {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(eot|svg|cur|jpg|png|webp|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2|ani)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My *package.json* contains:

```
"@angular/pwa": "^0.802.1",
"@angular/service-worker": "~8.2.0",
```

My *angular.json* contains:

```
"serviceWorker": true,
"ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
```

This is my *manifest.webmanifest*:

```
{
  "name": "postit",
  "short_name": "postit",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "/",
  "start_url": "/",
  "icons": [...]
}
```

I build using `ng build --prod` and deploy on my web server.

I get a `No matching service worker detected` warning:

[image: No matching service worker detected]

When I turn to offline mode:

[image: No internet connection]

What did I miss so that offline mode works?

Comment: The Chrome lighthouse tool shows no errors and validates as a PWA? You are testing from an HTTPS server (required for the PWA A2HS)?

Comment: Thank you, this was because of unsecured HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When doing the PWA testing on a non-localhost server you want to make sure it is HTTPS.
That is a core requirement.

Answer (score 0):

On LocalHost you can just test the app with Local Http server.

Try with

```
npm install http-server-spa
```

Then after making your build go to dist folder and run the server

```
http-server-spa / index.html
```

Check out youit will work.

Answer (score 0):

The PWA service worker will work with the prod version.
I found this issue but got fixed once I build it with
`ng build --prod`  instead of `ng build`

Comment: I was stuck 4 hours on this issue, Thanks man you solved my problem :-)